# core plot axisset for piechart not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot, pie-chart

I am trying to hide axis set for pie chart using `graph.axisset = nil;` but it is not working. Is there any other way to remove default axisset of graph.

```
CPTXYGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc]initWithFrame:self.hostingView.frame];
graph.borderColor = [CPTColor whiteColor].cgColor;
graph.paddingTop = 0.0f;
graph.paddingRight = 0.0f;
graph.paddingLeft = 0.0f;
graph.paddingBottom = 0.0f;
graph.axisSet = nil;
self.hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;

//Apply for theme to graph
self.graphTheme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme];
[graph applyTheme:self.graphTheme];
[graph release];
CPTPieChart *pieChart = [[CPTPieChart alloc]init];
pieChart.identifier = @"OverView";
pieChart.dataSource = self;
pieChart.sliceDirection = CPTPieDirectionClockwise;
pieChart.pieRadius = ((self.hostingView.frame.size.height  / 2) - 5);
pieChart.startAngle = M_PI;
CPTGraph *tempGraph = self.hostingView.hostedGraph;
[tempGraph addPlot:pieChart];
[pieChart release];
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `graph.axisSet = nil;` (note the capital "S").

Don't set the `borderColor` on the graph or any other Core Plot layer. Always use the Core Plot line style and fill properties to set the appearance of the various parts of the graph.

Comment: Can you provide more detail? How are you setting up the graph and plot? Are you getting any errors or log messages?