# Black color squared border appear in core plot piechart

Tags: ios, core-plot

```
CPTXYGraph *graph   = [[CPTXYGraph alloc]initWithFrame:self.hostingView.frame];
graph.borderColor   = [CPTColor whiteColor].cgColor;
graph.paddingTop    = 0.0f;
graph.paddingRight  = 0.0f;
graph.paddingLeft   = 0.0f;
graph.paddingBottom = 0.0f;
self.hostingView.hostedGraph = graph;
graph.axisSet = nil;


//Apply for theme to graph
self.graphTheme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme];
[graph applyTheme:self.graphTheme];
[graph release];

CPTPieChart *pieChart = [[CPTPieChart alloc]init];
pieChart.identifier = @"OverView";
pieChart.dataSource = self;
pieChart.sliceDirection = CPTPieDirectionClockwise;
pieChart.pieRadius = ((self.hostingView.frame.size.height  / 2) - 5);
pieChart.startAngle = M_PI;
CPTGraph *tempGraph = self.hostingView.hostedGraph;
    [tempGraph addPlot:pieChart];
[pieChart release];
```

For this code i am getting black colored border ,i thought that is due to graph axisSet but i don't how to remove.

Comment: PLease post ur entine method for drawing the pie chart,

Comment: possible duplicate of [core plot axisset for piechart not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984708/core-plot-axisset-for-piechart-not-working)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If what you're talking about is the border box that appears around the entire graph, I would say use this code after the statement `[graph applyTheme:self.graphTheme];`:

```
graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;
```

This removes the border completely from the graph area.